# Will a USB headset still work if the sound card in the PC has been disabled

Tags: sound-card, headset

I heard that if I use a headset on a system without a sound card or a disabled sound card it will still work. Meaning that I can hear sound and speak to users through a VoIP service such as Skype.

Is this true? Or did I mis-interpret wrongly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this forum thread](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies-archive.cfm/622630.html):

> USB headsets basically have a USB sound "card" integrated. For the Logi USB headsets that's a small unit integrated with the cord. You could pull your soundcard out of your PC and the USB headset will still give you sound.

Which makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, USB headsets are separate audio devices and work independently from built-in sound cards.

VoIP applications such as Skype let you choose your preferred audio device if more than one audio device is installed:

[image]

Comment: That is true!

Just make sure if you remove the headset that the computer selects the correct card. I haven't figure out why but after I remove my MS lifechat headset. Windows 7 always defaults to the SPDIF out.